# Can I use an incomplete sentense in listing?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> First, obtain a comprehensive understanding of the emissions level of
>   key pollutants, a foundation upon which to conduct pollution
>   abatement-related analyses.

Can I use an incomplete sentence in listing as shown in the example? I meant to use first, second, and third to indicate the research aims. I also want to use a parenthetical expression 'a foundation xxx' to modify the 'comprehensive understanding', thus to show the importance. Not sure if the sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: I don't think your example *is* an "incomplete sentence". It's a standard ***imperative*** construction (with subject ***You*** implied but not explicitly stated) that includes an [***appositive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) clause (where ***a foundation upon which to conduct pollution abatement-related analyses*** is an appositive restatement / redefinition of preceding ***a comprehensive understanding of the emissions level of key pollutants***). But I don't understand exactly what you're asking about here. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: ahh, yes, you are right, the second half is an appositive restatement. So it is grammatically correct, right? I am just afraid the sentence reads very awkward or difficult to be understood because the appositive restatement is very long and complicated.

Comment: No, it's fine. The pause in speech (or a comma, dash, or whatever in the written form) is all a native speaker needs, to make it easy to understand the syntax. Personally I'd probably use ***emission levels*** rather than ***the emissions level***, but that's just a stylistic choice. And there's nothing "wrong" with you choosing differently.

Comment: Thank you so much!!